# Matlab tiledlayout, how to create a tile with no axes or data

Tags: matlab, plot

I am working with Matlab (R2023a) and I am hoping to make a tiledlayout such that one of the tiles doesn't contain any axes or data, such that it is empty except for the title. I'm planning to put some text (multiple lines) in the title, which will describe the other tiles.

Is there a way to remove the axes and/or plotting area from a tile, so that the only element which appears is the title?

Comment: Did you try `axis off`?

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that has the effect I was looking for.